# Updated with data: Error in Diff...must be factors with the same levels

Tags: r, diff, factors, bradleyterry2

I hope you all can help me.

I have a list with two data frames -- `contests` and `expvar.`  In the data frame `contests`, each row is a match with the first column being the winner of the match, and the second column being the loser of the match.  In the data frame `expvar` I have player-specific predictor variables.  These are all numbers.  I am trying to use the BradleyTerry2 package to analyze my data.  Here is the code I am using:

```
a <- data.frame(read.csv(file.choose()))
b <- data.frame(read.csv(file.choose()))
ablist <- list(contests=a, expvar=b)  
Model <- BTm(1, winner, loser, ~level2[..]+(1|..), data=ablist)
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error in Diff(player1, player2, formula, id, data, separate.ability, refcat,  : 
'player1$..' and 'player2$..' must be factors with the same levels
```

My question is, what am I doing wrong?  I have tried many things, but I am not sure what this error means.  Should I change my variables into factors? Why/how?  The winners and losers all have the same categories of predictor variables.

Here is my output for `dput(a)`

```
structure(list(winner = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 
16L, 16L, 16L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 18L, 19L, 19L, 
19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 22L, 
22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 
24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 25L, 
25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 26L, 
26L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 29L, 
29L, 29L, 29L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 30L, 
30L, 30L, 30L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 31L, 23L, 13L, 
20L, 20L), .Label = c("Arizona Cardinals", "Atlanta Falcons", 
"Baltimore Ravens", "Buffalo Bills", "Carolina Panthers", "Chicago Bears", 
"Cincinnati Bengals", "Cleveland Browns", "Dallas Cowboys", "Denver Broncos", 
"Green Bay Packers", "Houston Texans", "Indianapolis Colts", 
"Jacksonville Jaguars", "Kansas City Chiefs", "Miami Dolphins", 
"Minnesota Vikings", "New England Patriots", "New Orleans Saints", 
"New York Giants", "New York Jets", "Oakland Raiders", "Philadelphia Eagles", 
"Pittsburgh Steelers", "San Diego Chargers", "San Francisco 49ers", 
"Seattle Seahawks", "St. Louis Rams", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", 
"Tennessee Titans", "Washington Redskins"), class = "factor"), 
    loser = structure(c(4L, 9L, 17L, 27L, 27L, 28L, 28L, 29L, 
    29L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 29L, 30L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 23L, 24L, 32L, 10L, 15L, 
    16L, 23L, 26L, 28L, 29L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 
    20L, 20L, 23L, 26L, 30L, 11L, 11L, 12L, 14L, 15L, 18L, 20L, 
    24L, 29L, 8L, 15L, 16L, 32L, 4L, 7L, 15L, 21L, 7L, 8L, 12L, 
    21L, 24L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 32L, 2L, 8L, 16L, 20L, 22L, 23L, 
    26L, 30L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 14L, 18L, 28L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 
    15L, 17L, 31L, 3L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 13L, 13L, 15L, 19L, 25L, 
    26L, 31L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 10L, 23L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 
    16L, 19L, 22L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 1L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 
    11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 20L, 21L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 10L, 16L, 17L, 
    22L, 23L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 2L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 23L, 26L, 27L, 
    30L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 24L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 32L, 1L, 4L, 
    4L, 7L, 16L, 17L, 19L, 29L, 31L, 10L, 13L, 16L, 22L, 30L, 
    1L, 2L, 8L, 9L, 21L, 25L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 3L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 
    8L, 8L, 9L, 13L, 15L, 19L, 26L, 32L, 10L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 
    22L, 23L, 23L, 30L, 4L, 11L, 22L, 28L, 29L, 29L, 32L, 22L, 
    27L, 29L, 29L, 9L, 32L, 2L, 5L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 16L, 18L, 20L, 
    28L, 3L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 
    25L, 1L, 8L, 9L, 11L, 20L, 24L, 24L, 28L, 7L, 18L, 29L, 32L
    ), .Label = c("Arizona Cardinals", "Atlanta Falcons", "Baltimore Ravens", 
    "Buffalo Bills", "Carolina Panthers", "Chicago Bears", "Cincinnati Bengals", 
    "Cleveland Browns", "Dallas Cowboys", "Denver Broncos", "Detroit Lions", 
    "Green Bay Packers", "Houston Texans", "Indianapolis Colts", 
    "Jacksonville Jaguars", "Kansas City Chiefs", "Miami Dolphins", 
    "Minnesota Vikings", "New England Patriots", "New Orleans Saints", 
    "New York Giants", "New York Jets", "Oakland Raiders", "Philadelphia Eagles", 
    "Pittsburgh Steelers", "San Diego Chargers", "San Francisco 49ers", 
    "Seattle Seahawks", "St. Louis Rams", "Tampa Bay Buccaneers", 
    "Tennessee Titans", "Washington Redskins"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("winner", 
"loser"), row.names = c(NA, -256L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here it is for `dput(b)`

```
structure(list(X = structure(1:32, .Label = c("Arizona Cardinals", 
"Atlanta Falcons", "Baltimore Ravens", "Buffalo Bills", "Carolina Panthers", 
"Chicago Bears", "Cincinnati Bengals", "Cleveland Browns", "Dallas Cowboys", 
"Denver Broncos", "Detroit Lions", "Green Bay Packers", "Houston Texans", 
"Indianapolis Colts", "Jacksonville Jaguars", "Kansas City Chiefs", 
"Miami Dolphins", "Minnesota Vikings", "New England Patriots", 
"New Orleans Saints", "New York Giants", "New York Jets", "Oakland Raiders", 
"Philadelphia Eagles", "Pittsburgh Steelers", "San Diego Chargers", 
"San Francisco 49ers", "Seattle Seahawks", "St. Louis Rams", 
"Tampa Bay Buccaneers", "Tennessee Titans", "Washington Redskins"
), class = "factor"), id = 1:32, high = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), level2 = c(0, 0.67, 
0, 0.33, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.25, 0.33, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.25, 
0.33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.67, 0.25, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.6), level3 = c(0.25, 
0.4, 0.36, 0.3, 0.11, 0.56, 0.38, 0.5, 0.22, 0.33, 0.6, 0.3, 
0.57, 0.38, 0.29, 0.43, 0.3, 0.33, 0.29, 0.14, 0.2, 0.22, 0.33, 
0.22, 0.5, 0.27, 0.4, 0.2, 0.43, 0.43, 0.33, 0.44)), .Names = c("X", 
"id", "high", "level2", "level3"), row.names = c(NA, -32L), class = "data.frame"
```

Thank you

Comment: Can you place the output from `dput(a)` and `dput(b)` to make this question reproducible. This is a data specific issue, to answer it, we need to see the data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Perhaps if you made a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) that demonstrates your question / problem, people would find it easier to answer. At the moment, your example isn't reproducible because you don't provide sample data.

Comment: Do you get the same error when you use the `flatlizards` dataset in that package?

Comment: Thank you mnel and Andrie.  I have edited the question above to include data.  Also, no, @sebastian-c, I do not get any error when I use the flatlizards dataset.

Comment: Hi mnel and @Andrie, is what I have edited above sufficient or do I need to include anything else?  Please let me know.  Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I also got stuck with this error message for the 'BTm' function.  The problem can be resolved by defining the levels.  (levels are a definable attribute for functions of type factor).  Try setting levels for player1 & player2:

```
    levels(contests[,1]) <- unique(c(contests[,1], contests[,2]))
    levels(contests[,2]) <- unique(c(contests[,1], contests[,2]))
```

Sorry I couldn't help 3 years ago ;)